# Looking for Winston_Churchill data

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I cannot imagine why does this work:

```
select * {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:birthName ?name.
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mahatma_Gandhi> dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
```

and this - NOT (empty bindings):

```
select * {
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Winston_Churchill> dbpedia-owl:birthName ?name.
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Winston_Churchill> dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Winston_Churchill> dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace}
OPTIONAL{<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Winston_Churchill> dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
```

on http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql

**UPD**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090691/1214162) is good but when I tried to look for Vincent_van_Gogh - same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbpedia:Mahatma_Gandhi` has `dbpedia-owl:birthName` *and* `dbpprop:birthName`. On the other hand `dbpedia:Winston_Churchill` has only `dbpprop:birthname` (note the different capitalization).

Not sure what the right way to deal with this is.

Comment: There wasn't any use of dbpprop in the question, though, was there?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor No, which is why the second query doesn't return anything.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I misread the answer.  I thought you were saying that there were no results because Winston *doesn't* have any dbpprop:birthname.  Mea culpa.

Comment: As to good ways to handle this, a property path isn't bad.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29090691/1281433) that shows how you could use *?wc dbpprop:birthname|dbpedia-owl:birthName ?birthName*.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a difference between DBpedia Live and DBpedia.  On the standard DBpedia, your query works without a problem:

- "Winston Leonard Spencer-Churchill"@en
- 1874-11-30+02:00
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/St_Martin's_Church,_Bladon
- 1965-01-24+02:00

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FWinston_Churchill%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthName%20%3Fname.%0D%0AOPTIONAL%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FWinston_Churchill%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FWinston_Churchill%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3ArestingPlace%20%3FrestingPlace%7D%0D%0AOPTIONAL%7B%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FWinston_Churchill%3E%20dbpedia-owl%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

As [svick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29090101/1281433) points out, in DBpedia Live, Churchill has a **dbpprop:birthname**, but not a **dbpedia-owl:birthName**.  What you can do in this case is ask for either one. You can do that easily with an 
alternation property path.  The following query works on DBpedial Live.  (I used values to bind **?wc** to **dbpedia:Winston_Churchill**, but that was just to make the query a little more readable.  The important part is the property path triple: **dbpedia:Winston_Churchill dbpedia-owl:birthName|dbpprop:birthname ?birthname**.

```sql
select * {
  values ?wc { dbpedia:Winston_Churchill }
  ?wc dbpedia-owl:birthName|dbpprop:birthname ?birthName
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate}
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace}
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
```

[DBpedia Live results](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fwc%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AWinston_Churchill%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthName%7Cdbpprop%3Abirthname%20%3FbirthName%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3ArestingPlace%20%3FrestingPlace%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Of course, if you take that back to the normal DBpedia where Churchill has both properties, you'll now get *two* results, one for each property.  If you want just a single result, you can ask for the properties separately and **bind** and **coalesce** them:

```sql
select ?birthName ?birthDate ?restingPlace ?deathDate {
  values ?wc { dbpedia:Winston_Churchill }
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:birthName ?birthname0 }
  optional { ?wc dbpprop:birthname ?birthname1 }
  bind ( coalesce(?birthname0,?birthname1) as ?birthName )
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birthDate}
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:restingPlace ?restingPlace}
  optional { ?wc dbpedia-owl:deathDate ?deathDate}
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3FbirthName%20%3FbirthDate%20%3FrestingPlace%20%3FdeathDate%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fwc%20%7B%20dbpedia%3AWinston_Churchill%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthName%20%3Fbirthname0%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpprop%3Abirthname%20%3Fbirthname1%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20bind%20%28%20coalesce%28%3Fbirthname0%2C%3Fbirthname1%29%20as%20%3FbirthName%20%29%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3ArestingPlace%20%3FrestingPlace%7D%0D%0A%20%20optional%20%7B%20%3Fwc%20dbpedia-owl%3AdeathDate%20%3FdeathDate%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Thanks for so complete explanation, it is supergood! Another thing I'd like to kindly ask you to share about is what will be the best approach for quering live.dbpedia information on different kinds of pages, e.g. now we were playing with Ghandi and Churchill and they are people so asking for birthdate is okay, but if i'd like to go for Cities pages data quering... where can I look for any different spelling and format of each property? Like dbpedia-owl:birthName|dbpprop:birthname and so on. Thanks

Comment: ...and again, just replacing Churchill with Vincent_van_Gogh... no results

Comment: @IvanFazaniuk Is there a reason you want to query live.dbpedia.org instead of dbpedia.org?

Comment: actually i've just thought it has more actual data. For example Cities' Mayor may changed and dbpedia has a 6 month lag, AFAIK